# Upload Image and indicating response in a table with axios and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, axios

[image]I want to upload 10 images together and send a `axios` request to backend to do some calculations with those 10 files , after calculations there will be response as `{imagename: true}` or `{imagename: false}` receiving the response from backend I want to list those 10 images on frontend with a indication that the calculation is true or false.

This is what I tried but I'm stuck after getting response and unable to show the true or false status.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import axios, { post } from 'axios';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Styles from '../styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';

import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';




class ImageUploader extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      file:null,
      user_name:this.props.username,
      checkboxcolor:false,
      detailsResoponse:[],
      responseList:[],
      imageList:[],
      uploadResponse:'priya',
      a:[],
      loaded: 0
    }
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handelFile = this.handelFile.bind(this)
    this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
  }
  
  onFormSubmit(){
    this.setState({
        responseList:[]
    })
    var files=this.state.file
    for(var i in files){
        this.fileUpload(files[i])
        .then((response)=>{
            // console.log(response.data);
        })
    }
  }


handelFile(e) {
    if(e.target.files.length == 10) {
        var self=this
        self.setState({
            imgList:[],
            file:e.target.files,
        })
        for(var i in e.target.files){
            if(i != 'length' && i != 'item'){
                if(e.target.files[i].type.split('/')[0] == 'image'){
                   self.state.imageList.push(e.target.files[i])
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    else{
        alert('Please upload 10 images')
    }     
}

urlBlob(id,file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {

        var image=document.getElementById(id)
        image.src=e.target.result
            
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
}


fileUpload(file){
    const url = 'http://abc';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image',file)
   
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        }
    }
    return  axios.post(url,formData,config)
    .then(res => {

        var jsondata=JSON.stringify(res.data)
        JSON.parse(jsondata, (key, value) => {
            // if (value == true) {
                // this.state.a.push(key)
                var arrayList= this.state.responseList
                arrayList.push(res.data)
                    this.setState({
                        responseList:arrayList,
                        // checkboxcolor:true
                     })
            // }
          });
        }
     )
    .catch(function (error) {
      alert(error)
  });
}


  render(){
    const { classes } = this.props;
    console.log(this.state.a)
    console.log(this.state.imageList,"yep")
    // console.log(this.state.responseList,"responseList")
    return (
      <div>
          <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                        <AppBar position="static" color="inherit" className={classes.app}>
                            <Toolbar>
                            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
                              Upload Image
                            </Typography>
                            </Toolbar>
                        </AppBar>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                   
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                       <Paper elevation={3} style={{padding:20,height:25,marginBottom:20}}> 
                            <input 
                                  id="fileItem"
                                   type="file" onChange={this.handelFile}
                                   multiple
                            />
                            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.onFormSubmit}> Upload</Button>
                       </Paper>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                            <Table style={{width:'80%',position:'relative',left:'8%',border:'2px solid lightgrey',marginTop:'3%'}}>
                            <TableHead> 
                                <TableRow >
                                    <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}> Checkbox </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}> Image </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}> Name </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}> Username</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell style={{width:'10%'}}></TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                        </Table>
                        <Scrollbars style={{height: 328}}>

                        {this.state.imageList.map((item,key)=> (
                            <Table style={{width:'80%',position:'relative',left:'8%',border:'2px solid lightgrey',borderTop:'0px'}}>
                                <TableBody>
                                        <TableRow key={key}>
                                            <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}>

                                                {this.state.checkboxcolor ? 
                                            
                                                    <FormControlLabel
                                                        control={
                                                            <Checkbox
                                                                checked={this.state.checkboxcolor}
                                                            />
                                                        }
                                                />
                                            :
                                                null
                                        
                                             }
                                             
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}>
                                                <img id={"image"+key} src={this.urlBlob("image"+key,item)} height="90" width="90" /> 
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}>{item.name}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}>{/* {this.state.user_name} */}user_name</TableCell>
                                            
                                            <TableCell> 
                                               
                                            </TableCell>

                                     </TableRow>
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                        ))}
                         </Scrollbars>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
      </div>
   )
  }
}

export default compose(withStyles(Styles))(ImageUploader);
```

`console.log(res.data)` response

[image: console.log(res.data) response]

Comment: Hey welcome to SO. Can you please share the console log of response.data i.e., .then((response)=>{
            // console.log(response.data);
        }) and where do you want to show the status?

Comment: @Think-Twice hii , i have attached a image how i want to show the status and .then((response)=>{ // console.log(response.data); }) i am getting undefined .

Comment: Okey what you get here --> return  axios.post(url,formData,config)
    .then(res => { do console log of res.data console.log(res.data) and share

Comment: {1.jpeg: false}1.jpeg: false__proto__: Object "res.data" . , {7.jpeg: true} "res.data" .. and so on . ... i have attached the image after the code as console.log(res.data)

Comment: Hi, can you tell me first do you want to display the images which is stored in your local once it is uploaded or do you want display the images getting it from the backend (I mean through API request) ?

Comment: images will be uploaded from local and then a request will be send after that i ill recieve a resonponse so that i can mark a image true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** To fix below issue you need to add **event.persist()** under handleFile function.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

I updated all the code using ES6.

I noticed some bad practices in your code and corrected them

1. The way you push elements to state array is not right instead use
   previous state to play with array in react state.
2. Stop using var
   instead use let and const
3. Stop assigning this to self instead use arrow
   functions so that you no need to do manual binding and no need to depend on local variable i.e., self

I have corrected your code. This code will show the image responses as you needed

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import axios, { post } from 'axios';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Styles from '../styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

class ImageUploader extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      file:null,
      user_name:this.props.username,
      detailsResoponse:[],
      responseList:[],
      imageList:[],
      uploadResponse:'priya',
      a:[],
      loaded: 0
    }
  }

  onFormSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({
        responseList:[]
    })
    let files = this.state.file;
    for(var i in files){
      this.fileUpload(files[i]);
    }
  }

handelFile = e => {
    e.persist();
if(e.target.files.length == 10) {
    this.setState({
        imgList:[],
        file:e.target.files,
    })
   for(let i=0; i < e.target.files.length; i++){
      if(e.target.files[i].type.split('/')[0] == 'image'){
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          imageList: [...prevState.imageList, e.target.files[i]]
        }));
      }
    }       
}
else{
    alert('Please upload 10 images')
}     
}

urlBlob = (id,file) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
        let image = document.getElementById(id);
        image.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
}


fileUpload = file => {
    const url = 'http://172.16.92.21:9999';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image',file)
    formData.append('uname','150180')
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        }
    }
    axios.post(url, formData, config)
    .then(res => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            responseList: [...prevState.responseList, res.data]
          }));
        });
    .catch(error => {
      alert(error)
  });
}


  render(){
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { responseList } = this.props;
    console.log(this.state.a)
    console.log(this.state.imageList,"yep")
    // console.log(this.state.responseList,"responseList")
    const imagesResponse = responseList && responseList.map((image, index) => {
      return <li className="list-group-item">{image}</li>
    });
    return (
      <div>
          <Grid>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <ul className="list-group">
                    {imagesResponse}
                  </ul>
                </Col>
              </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                        <AppBar position="static" color="inherit" className={classes.app}>
                            <Toolbar>
                            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
                              Upload Image For Surveillance
                            </Typography>
                            </Toolbar>
                        </AppBar>
                    </Col>
                </Row>


                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                       <Paper elevation={3} style={{padding:20,height:25,marginBottom:20}}> 
                            <input 
                                  id="fileItem"
                                   type="file" onChange={this.handelFile}
                                   multiple
                            />
                            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.onFormSubmit}> Upload</Button>
                       </Paper>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                            <Table style={{width:'80%',position:'relative',left:'8%',border:'2px solid lightgrey',marginTop:'3%'}}>
                            <TableHead> 
                                <TableRow >
                                    <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}> Checkbox </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}> Image </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}> Name </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}> Username</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell style={{width:'10%'}}></TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                        </Table>
                        <Scrollbars style={{height: 328}}>

                        {this.state.imageList && this.state.imageList.map((item,key)=> (
                            <Table style={{width:'80%',position:'relative',left:'8%',border:'2px solid lightgrey',borderTop:'0px'}}>
                                <TableBody>
                                        <TableRow key={key}>
                                            <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}>

                                                {responseList ? responseList.map((image, index) => {
                                                  return (<FormControlLabel key={index}
                                                        control={
                                                            <Checkbox
                                                                checked={item.name == image.name && image.flag ? true : false }
                                                            />
                                                        }
                                                    />)
                                                }): <FormControlLabel
                                                        control={
                                                            <Checkbox
                                                                checked={false}
                                                            />
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                               }



                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}>
                                                <img id={"image"+key} src={this.urlBlob("image"+key,item)} height="90" width="90" /> 
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}>{item.name}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell className={classes.phPadding}>{/* {this.state.user_name} */}user_name</TableCell>

                                            <TableCell> 

                                            </TableCell>

                                     </TableRow>
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                        ))}
                         </Scrollbars>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
      </div>
   )
  }
}

export default compose(withStyles(Styles))(ImageUploader);
```

Please test from your side and let me know

Comment: Thankyou i will improve my bad practices from now. here i =n your code i am getting few errors warning.js?6327:33 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()

Comment: Where exactly you get those warnings I mean in which handler function?

Comment: I want to show a tick mark for for those whose response is true

Comment: Will you be able to get the response in following format from backed like {"name": "7.jpeg", "flag": true}

Comment: ya i will be able to @Think twice

Comment: @BhartSupriya   I have updated my answer. Please give a try in your machine. Your back-end response should be in this format  {"name": "7.jpeg", "flag": true} for my answer to work. Let me know if you encounter any issues

Comment: sir getting error like this on line 58 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

Comment: as soon as i select 10 images i get error like this

Comment: Ok Let me check that. I think this issue is after changing to arrow function of handleFile right?

Comment: Will you be able to create a sandbox with your code?

Comment: Or can you click on the file and let me know in which line of code that throws the error?

Comment: line no 59  imageList: [...prevState.imageList, e.target.files[i]]n and while selecting if i am selction upto 9 images that error is not there but if i am selction 10 images at once it throws error

Comment: @BhartSupriya Hey updated my code can you please give a try once

Comment: @BhartSupriya you are trying on old code. Please take my updated code and try

Comment: @BhartSupriya Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180536/discussion-between-think-twice-and-bhart-supriya).